# percona backup and restore

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I'm trying to use percona xtrabackup to backup a mysql database.  in the restoring the database according to the [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/xtrabackup_bin/restoring_a_backup.html):

```
rsync -avrP /data/backup/ /var/lib/mysql/
```

this will copy the ibdata1 as well.
what if I have want to restore the backup into an existing mysql instance with some some existing databases? would this corrupt my other databases? clearly this will overwrite existing ibdata1.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a local http/php server, so *in case you don't need to batch import or export* information, I suggest you use a database manager app that can import or export as `sql`, `csv` or `tsv` files.

I use a web-based admin tool called [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/) and it works great (plus, it's just a single php file). It has options to export or import a whole database or just certain tables and even specific registers. Its usage is pretty straightforward.